# How can I create a table with calculated cells, not columns, in PowerBI?

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to perform several calculations on a Table1, 
e.g:

```
Measure1 = AVERAGE(Table1[Column1])
Measure2 = SUM(Table1[Column2]) 
etc.
```

Then, I want to put these calculations in another Table2 so that the result is:

```
TextA1; TextA2; Measure1
TextB1; TextB2; Measure2
```

The TextA1 etc are not contained in Table1, they are my own text/descriptions.

How can I create that table/matrix/visual?

I was thinking to first create a table as:

```
TextA1; TextA2; 
TextB1; TextB2;
```

I then created an index column in that table. I then tried to create another table with Calculated Columns as the Measure1 and Measure2 and to name these columns 1 and 2. I was hoping that I could transpose this table and then join it with the text table above based on the index numbers but it did not work.

Is there any solution?

Comment: Does the text relate to `Table1`?

Comment: No, it is totally irrelevant with Table1 and independent.